# Looping over multiple variables in Pug

Tags: javascript, html, pug

I'm struggling with finding the correct way to declare these variables in a loop.. I need the variables to loop in two different places in the block.

First const `breadcrumbsItems`: Has to loop in the `span` tag.

Second const `breadcrumbsAttributes`: Has to loop in the `(data-trigger="")`

Can anyone please help me figuring it out?
Thanks in advance

```
   
- const breadcrumbsItems = [ `John`, `Jane`, `Jefferson`,  `Ramirez` ]
- const breadcrumbsAttributes = ['tabOne','tabTwo', 'tabThree', 'tabFour']
     
  .breadcrumbs
    ul.breadcrumbs__list
      li.breadcrumbs__elements
        a.breadcrumbs__tabs.is-selected(data-trigger="#{const breadcrumbsAttributes}")
          span.breadcrumbs__item #{const breadcrumbsItems}
          svg.breadcrumbs__icon
            use(xlink:href="assets/defs.svg#icon-close")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop over one of the arrays, then use the index of the loop to access the corresponding value in the other array:

```
ul
  each item, i in breadcrumbItems
    li
      button(data-trigger= breadcrumbsAttributes[i])
        span #{item}
```

Also, try to always use buttons instead of links to perform actions that don't navigate the user to new content.

Comment: It took my some tweaking but in the end it worked!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need nested iterations. You can use each.
Here's an example that you can match to fit your markup.

Examples can also be found under the [code section of the docs](https://pugjs.org/language/code.html).

You can throw this code in a codepen.io and add pug as an html preprocessor if you ever want to quickly play with some pug markup.

```
- const breadcrumbsItems = [ `John`, `Jane`, `Jefferson`,  `Ramirez` ]
- const breadcrumbsAttributes = ['tabOne','tabTwo', 'tabThree', 'tabFour']

each item in breadcrumbsItems
  a.example(data-trigger=item) #{item}
    each attr in breadcrumbsAttributes
      div #{attr}
```

Another common confusion is when to use #{} and when not to.
If you are declaring attributes like this a(data-trigger=var), the inside of the parenthesis are treated like javascript. So no #{}.

If you are inside a text or markup area, you use #{}.

Comment: Problem is that nested iterations loop over themselves, meaning that for each `#{item}` looped there are gonna be 4 `#{attr}`looped over